# setcookie() PHP not working with variables

Tags: php, html, cookies

I need to set cookies in an assignment. When I set them using a string, ie `setcookie('Name', 'John', time() + 86400)` it works, but when using a PHP variable, ie `setcookie('Name', $name, time() + 86400)` the cookie is not set.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have echoed out the $name variable on my page and it shows up so I know that is being set. When I display the cookie using `$_COOKIE['Name']`, it works when it received a string, but doesn't when it's a `PHP variable`.

## order01.php

```
<form action="order02.php" class="formLayout">
 <div class="formGroup">
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" class="textbox" autofocus 
  required placeholder="First name" title="first name" 
  maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z'-]{2,20}">
 </div>
 <div class="formGroup">
  <label> Car model:</label>
  <div class="formElements">
   <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Mustang">Ford Mustang<br>
   <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Subaru">Subaru WRX 
STI<br>
   <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Corvette">Corvette<br>
  </div>
 </div>


<?php
 $name = $_GET['fname'];
 $model = $_GET['model'];

 //write cookies for name and model for 1 day
 setcookie('Name', $name, time() + 86400);
 setcookie('Model', $model, time() + 86400);
?>
```

## order02.php

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['Name'])){
 echo "Cookie ".$_COOKIE['Name']." is set";
}
else{
 echo "<div class='pageContainer'>";
 echo "<h2 class='containerText, centerText'>Failed to validate inputs";
 echo "<br><br>";
 echo "<a href='order01.php'><button>Go Back</button></a>";
 echo "</div>";
 exit();
}
```

Comment: you are trying to get `fname`  input value into `php` variable which is wrong. `var_dump($name)` your `$name` and check are you getting any value  in it?

Comment: I did var_dump($name) when i put in 'bobby' into the form and it outputted string(5) "bobby" @MuhammadShareyar

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code, first, there is no closing `</form>` tag and second you have to submit  your form on `order01.php` where you are saving your `cookie` so try this and it will work

Order01.php

```
<form action="order01.php" class="formLayout">
<div class="formGroup">
 <label>First name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="fname" class="textbox" autofocus 
 required placeholder="First name" title="first name" 
 maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z'-]{2,20}">
</div>
<div class="formGroup">
 <label> Car model:</label>
 <div class="formElements">
  <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Mustang">Ford Mustang<br>
 <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Subaru">Subaru WRX STI<br>
 <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Corvette">Corvette<br>
</div>

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Order02.php

```
  <?php

 $name = $_GET['fname'];
 $model = $_GET['model'];

 //write cookies for name and model for 1 day
 setcookie('Name', $name, time() + 86400);
 setcookie('Model', $model, time() + 86400);

if(isset($_COOKIE['Name'])){
  echo "Cookie ".$_COOKIE['Name']." is set";
 }
 else{
   echo "<div class='pageContainer'>";
   echo "<h2 class='containerText, centerText'>Failed to validate inputs";
   echo "<br><br>";
   echo "<a href='order01.php'><button>Go Back</button></a>";
   echo "</div>";
   exit();
  }
```

?>

Comment: I have a </form> I just didn't include it because I tried to not put in a not important code in my question. So if I change the action to order01.php, how do I get to order02.php? The cookie is set correctly if I use a string so it is succesfully getting set when the action = "order02.php"

Comment: you can do 2 things , 1- You can store your cookie values in your `order02.php` , 2- You can save your cookies values in your `order01.php` as i suggest and after storing the cookie values you can redirect it to your `order02.php` file

Comment: My cookie values are being saved, just not when I’m using a PHP variable. That is my issue.

Comment: It is because you are not submitting your form on `order01.php` if you want to submit your form on `order02.php` then you have to set cookies in that file , check i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Must not be output before cookies line like (echo, print_r() and HTML tags)

You can write the cookies code before any output

```
 <?php
  $name = $_GET['fname'];
  $model = $_GET['model'];

 //write cookies for name and model for 1 day
  setcookie('Name', $name, time() + 86400);
  setcookie('Model', $model, time() + 86400);
       ?>

<form action="order01.php" class="formLayout">
 <div class="formGroup">
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" class="textbox" autofocus required placeholder="First name" title="first name" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z'-]{2,20}">
</div>
<div class="formGroup">
   <label> Car model:</label>
   <div class="formElements">
    <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Mustang">Ford Mustang<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Subaru">Subaru WRX STI<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model" required value="Corvette">Corvette<br>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </div>
 </form>
```